# Code shows the segmentation fault but I am not able to find it out

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

When I was working on the linked list in a program the adds two polynomials using linked list and when I compiled it in my laptop it printed an infinite loop but online compilation showed segmentation fault I have checked all the pointers but I was not able to find it out, can you help me with that ?
my input polynomials are:

-polynomial 1= x^8 +5x^4 -7x^2 +6x

-polynomial 2= x^9 +7x^5 -3x^4 +2x^3

- create_list program creates the list
- insert program inserts the node at given position
- add_polynomials prog. adds two polynomials

---

```
struct node {
    float cofficient;
    int exponent;
    struct  node *next;
};  
struct node *create_list()
{
    struct node *head,*newnode,*temp;
    printf("enter the number of terms:\n");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==0){
        printf("creating empty list\n");
        struct node *head=NULL;
        return head;
    }   
    int i=1;
    newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("enter the cofficient and expression of term %d:\n",i);
    scanf("%f%d",&newnode->cofficient,&newnode->exponent);
    newnode->next=NULL;
    head=newnode;
    temp=head;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
        newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("enter the cofficient and expression of term %d:\n",i);
        scanf("%f%d",&newnode->cofficient,&newnode->exponent);
        newnode->next=NULL;
        temp->next=newnode;
        temp=newnode;
    }
    return head;
}

void display(struct node *start)
{
    if(start==NULL){
        printf("nothing to display\n");
    }
    struct node *p=start;
    int i=1;
    while(p != NULL){
        //printf("for term %d:\n",i++);
        printf("%.1fx^(%d)  ",p->cofficient,p->exponent);
        if(p->next->cofficient  >0)
        printf("+");
        p=p->next;
    }
}
struct node *insert(struct node *start,float coff,int expo)
{
    struct node *newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    newnode->cofficient=coff;
    newnode->exponent=expo;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(start ==NULL){
        printf("inserting in the empty list...\n");
        start=newnode;
        return start;
    }
    if(newnode->exponent > start->exponent){
        newnode->next=start;
        start=newnode;
        return start;
    }
    struct node *temp,*p=start;
    while(p->next != NULL){
        temp=p->next;
        if(temp->exponent <= newnode->exponent){
        p->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=temp;
        return start;
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
    if(newnode->exponent < p->exponent){
        p->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        return start;
    }
}
struct node *add_polynomials(struct node *start1,struct node *start2)
{
    struct node *p1,*p2;
    p1=start1;
    p2=start2;
    //struct node *newnode;
    struct node *p3_start=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    //p3_start=NULL;
    while(p1 != NULL && p2 != NULL){
        if(p1->exponent > p2->exponent){
            p3_start=insert(p3_start,p1->cofficient,p1->exponent);
            p1=p1->next;
            //continue;
        }
        else if(p1->exponent < p2->exponent){
            p3_start=insert(p3_start,p2->cofficient,p2->exponent);
            p2=p2->next;
            //continue;
            
        }
        else if(p1->exponent == p2->exponent){
            p3_start=insert(p3_start,p1->cofficient +p2->cofficient,p1->exponent);
            p1=p1->next;
            p2=p2->next;
        }
    }
    while(p1 != NULL){
        
        p3_start=insert(p3_start,p1->cofficient,p1->exponent);
        p1=p1->next;
    }
    while(p2 != NULL){
        
        p3_start=insert(p3_start,p2->cofficient,p2->exponent);
        p2=p2->next;
    }
    return p3_start;
}



    
int main () 
{
    struct node *p1_head,*p2_head,*p3_head;
    p1_head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    p1_head=create_list();
    p2_head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    p2_head=create_list();
    p3_head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    p3_head=add_polynomials(p1_head,p2_head);
    display(p3_head);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Launch your debugger, find out which line that is crashing and then include that information with your question.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on your own? Run your program in a debugger - at the very minimum that will get you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. You can also use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help find memory related bugs.

Comment: There are many issues. First of all you need to understand that `p1_head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));` followed by `p1_head=create_list();` is pointless. It's just like having `a = 5;` followed directly by `a = 42;`. Your code is full of these problems. Also the whole code is very convoluted.

Comment: What is your input data to the program?

Comment: When you run the program you get the questions: enter the number of terms: and so on. It would be easier to test if you provide your input values.

Answer (score 0):

When testing this I needed to change in function display

```
if(p->next->cofficient  >0)
    printf("+");
```

to

```
if(p->next != NULL)
    if(p->next->cofficient  >0)
        printf("+");
```

Else you try to dereference the pointer p->next which is null.
If you learn how to run the code in a debugger these types of errors are trivial to find.